# This vs. Holder for ObjectWrap::Unwrap

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

The [`v8::FunctionCallbackInfo`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-5.0/dd/d0d/classv8_1_1_function_callback_info.html) class distinguishes between `This` and `Holder`. I know what `this` is in JavaScript, and assume that `This` reflects that setting. But I have only a vague notion of what `Holder` is, and very little idea as to when I should use `Holder` instead of `This`.

**In particular, when writing a nan-based node.js extension and unwrapping an `ObjectWrap`, which of these should I pass?**

Currently [`node::ObjectWrap` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects) has examples using `Holder` while [current `Nan::ObjectWrap` documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/367e82a60fbaa52716232cc89db1cc3f685d77d9/doc/object_wrappers.md) uses `This`, so “just follow the examples in the documentation” doesn't help answering this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing the question above, I did some more digging and eventually found some relevant threads on the [v8-users Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/v8-users). I'll quote a short portion of the two posts which seem most relevant to me, but they are taken out of context, so the containing threads may well be worth reading for further information. Formatting markup added by me.

[Christian 'Little Jim' Plesner wrote in 2009:](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/Axf4hF_RfZo/hA6Mvo78AqAJ)

> In short: if you specify, through a `Signature`, that a function must
>   only be called on instances of function template `T`, the value returned
>   by `Holder` is guaranteed to hold an instance created from `T` or another
>   function template that directly or indirectly
>   `FunctionTemplate::Inherit`s from `T`.  No guarantees hold about the
>   type of `This`.

This statement is referenced by [Stephan Beal in 2010](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/fK9PBWxJxtQ/se3__JzvWaIJ). Later in that same thread, [Anton Muhin wrote:](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/fK9PBWxJxtQ/mIrdysLCrBQJ)

> Overall `Holder` should be always in the prototype chain of `This` and
>   hence if you read the property, you can freely use both.  However
>   setting the property would behave differently if `This() != Holder()`
>   — the property would end at different object.

This aspect is again [repeated by Ben Noordhuis in 2014](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/v8-users/tGn-haPr36M/bDkfA12NjQEJ).

The first statement seems to suggest that `Holder` is correct and nan documentation should be changed. The latter reminds us that in general, `This` is more appropriate *unless* one is directly interacting with some internal state like `ObjectWrap` does.

The example given in the first of the quoted posts about how `This` could be of an unexpected type was the following:

```js
var x = { }
x.__proto__ = document;
var div = x.createElement('div');
```

For that he wrote that “for compatibility reasons we have to allow
this”. Trying the same with a nan-based extension type (from the nan test suite) I find that these days the above appears to result in a `TypeError: Illegal invocation`. So apparently the signature verification semantics have changed somewhat. It doesn't seem to matter much for `ObjectWrap::Unwrap` these days whether you use `This` or `Holder`. Things look different for Node 0.10, though, so I think `Holder` should be preferred at least for methods, and filed [nan pull request #524](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/pull/524) about this.

The situation for accessors is much more complicated. Using `Holder()` won't work for accessors installed on the prototype, so apparently one either has to install accessors on the instance template, or use `This` and do some manual type checking.